# Creating an Access Form that enters data into a Table with one ID over multiple rows

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am wanting to enter data into an Access Table through the use of an Access Form.

There is one aspect of how I want the database to be designed that I cannot get to work.

I wish to have one ID over multiple rows with the data for each row coming from a separate text box in the form.

A bit hard to explain in words so I have attached some screenshots:

For the below example, we have an ID (corresponding to a person) and their Qualifications.

**This is how I would like to enter the data in a form:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDbvH.jpg

**This is how I would like to have the above data displayed in the Table:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJOMD.jpg

I understand this is not ideal nor is it correct use of a database. However, I have been instructed to do it in this way and do not have a choice in the matter.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, this isnt effective in an operational relational database

However , if it's really what you want, the easiest way is:

1. Add to your table an autoincrement column and make it primary key. I urge you to name this column "ID" as it's what it will really be. You don't have to display this column on your form, its Access "internal cooking".
2. Rename your actual "ID" column in "PersonID" or whatever you want and make it indexed with duplicates.